# dict get of dict from nested dictionary, creates a copy in tcl?

Tags: dictionary, copy, tcl

Let look at the sample code below:

```
set m [ dict create 1 [ dict create 2 3] 4 [ dict create 5 6 ] ]
set p [ dict get $m 4 ]
```

Now, here is the question. Assuming that I make no changes to the p.
Is TCL creating another copy, or is p just a pointer?
Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to know the expected behaviour. Not "try and see what happens", so that I know what I can rely on, and what I can report as a bug.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl's semantic model is of immutable values, i.e., when you are looking at a value, nothing that happens elsewhere in the world makes that value change. (Variables can change, but that's by putting a *different value* into them.) A consequence of this is that Tcl can aggressively share references to values. This means that its collection values (lists and dictionaries) hold these references efficiently, and the `dict get` operation will simply copy a reference out; the actual value itself exists in neither place, but the dictionary and the value both have handles for it. It looks just like a copy, but it's more efficient.

There is an additional nuance: when a variable has the *only* reference to a value, operations on the variable can directly modify the value instead of having to copy. That's very much not something you can see however, except that it boosts performance.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't create a new copy until there is a change through one of the "owners" of the object.

But `p` still isn't a pointer. For all programming intents and purposes, it's just a plain variable holding av value.